# JMockit match against null

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

```
      new Expectations() {{
        someMethod.getLocalObj().getValue((SomeClass)any);
        returns(1);
        times=1;

        request.doSomething().setTransaction((null)any); // HERE****how to match ??
        times=0;
    }};
```

Hi. I'm trying to match against a method that sets a variable to null. How can I do this in JMockit?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: I saw that you retracted your comment about problems with my answer; thus I assume that it worked for you. If so, please accept my answer; if not; feel free to let me know to see if I can help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this method here: [withNull()](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#withNull--):

*Same as withEqual(Object), but checking that an invocation argument in the replay phase is null.*